# Is there any way to keep name of file(+ date hour)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, find

I want to keep the output of this command as it is but I don't want the path, only the file name.

ex. `04-06-2020 23:09:02 filename` not `04-06-2020 23:09:02 /root/dir1/dir2/filename`

This is the command:

```
find path -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%TT %p\n' | sort -r
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `%p` to `%f`.

```
find path -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%TT %f\n' | sort -r
```

> `%f` File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).
>   `%p` File's name.

<sup>[Source](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it is better set the date as $ date +"%F %T" so that you can sort it in time order.

The solution is to apply the command basename file to each file in a list. Like this.
Create a file called shorts and put it in ~/bin/ directory.
 $  **chmod u+x ~/bin/shorts**
The file contains bash code:-

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -z "$1" ]] && echo "usage: shorts file_with_date_file_list.txt" && exit 9
declare -a f=()
while read data 
do 
    f=( $data )
    f[2]=$(basename ${f[2]})
    echo ${f[@]}
done < $1
```

Now the f[2] is because you have 3 columns if you have only 2 change the 2s to 1s.